# How could the neutrino be a Dirac particle

Tags: standard-model, dirac-equation, neutrinos, majorana-fermions

I'm reading up about neutrinos now and I understand the possibility of neutrinos being Majorana particles and further theories can be thought of from that (like the seesaw mechanism).

I'm still very confused why we haven't ruled out the possibility of the neutrino being a dirac particle yet. It being a Dirac particle implies it has a right-handed particle (and a left handed anti-particle).
How can a right handed neutrino exists without us being able to detect it? Is this what they mean by sterile neutrino or is there a similar mechanism at play like the seesaw mechanism (where the right-handed neutrino is so big we cannot detect it in our experiment)?

Comment: Yes, a right-chiral particle would be sterile, of course, since it does not participate in the charged-current weak interaction. How would you propose to detect it? Forget about see-saws for this one.

Comment: PS it does not participate in the neutral current weak  interaction, either, exceptionally,  in case you were getting ideas....